# How to fix Failure predicted on Primary Slave: WDC

Tags: windows-xp, window

This is an annoying message that I get when I restart the computer: *Failure predicted on Primary Slave: WDC.... Immediatelly back-up your data and replace your hard drive* I have tried it all. I even tried with another hard drive but the problem remains. I changed everything in the BIOS boot, primary master and slave but nothing happens. This is the configuration I have on the BIOS right now:

**In the main menu I have this configuration:**

Primary Master  : Auto

Primary Slave   : WDC WD600AB-00BVA0

Secondary Master: Pioneer DVD

Secondary Slave : Asus CD

**In the boot menu I have these configuration:**

1. ATAPI CD-ROM: Pioneer DVD
2. IDE Hard Drive:  WDC WD600AB-00BVA0
3. Removable Device: Disabled
4. Other Boot Device: Disabled
   Silent Boot Enabled

I have tried to disable the SMART monitoring but it doesn't fix the problem besides it shouldnt be disabled. The weird thing is that this is happening with two different hard drives. Is there something I'm missing folks.

Comment: Check the output of [DiskSmartView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/disk_smart_view.html). It could turn out to be a *real* problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "fix" hard drive problems. You back up the data and replace the drive.

That said, using different utilities to get a "second opinion" can be useful so that you aren't needlessly replacing disks when it's the controller's problem and not the drives.

UPDATE for comment from OP:

Re-reading question and seeing your response below, I think we can agree that the controller is bad, not all three drives.

Unfortunately, as the controller that does the SMART checking is probably firmly attached to the mainboard, unless there is an explicit setting in the BIOS, you're going to have to replace the MoBo. Which is probably a good idea anyway: If you're getting SMART errors from a failing controller, there's no telling what'll break next.

Comment: And what would those "different utilities" be? Because i've tried with 3 different hard drives without success.

Answer (score 0):

Your power supply could be the cause of you problem. Try disconnecting the power connectors from your DVD/CD drives and see if you still get the messages.